# Migrating dagger from kapt to ksp

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, kapt

last time I tried to migrate from kapt to ksp, all libraries with no problem instead of dagger...
[see libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTYDM.png)

dagger2_version '2.47'

I got the error logs:
e: [ksp] Cannot use legacy dagger.spi.BindingGraphPlugin while compiling with KSP: Dagger/Android/DuplicateAndroidInjectors. Either compile with KAPT or migrate the plugin to implement dagger.spi.model.BindingGraphPlugin.
e: Error occurred in KSP, check log for detail

Anyone has similar problem? I cannot find nothing with that

Comment: Dagger does not support KSP (yet). See [feature request on github](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2349#issuecomment-1549890357).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, when I updated dagger and dagger-compiler and removed android support:

```kotlin
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.48'
    ksp 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.48'

    // Android support removed
    //implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.48'
    //implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.48'
    //ksp 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48'
```

Comment: Also dagger ksp support is currently at alpha. I used these instructions from dagger.dev:
https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ksp.html

Comment: Dagger 2.49 added support for dagger-android https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.49